# Laravel Passport API call always return Unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

So I have setup my API with Passport and tried to make GET request for almost a week now but still getting the response bellow :

```
{
"message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Below are my configuration :

## Auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        //'hash' => true,
    ],
],
```

## AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    //
    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(7));

   Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(14));



}
```

## RouteServiceProvider

```
 protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('auth:api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

## Controller : Token request function using user credentials as per [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport)

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
     $http = new Client();
    $token_url=url('oauth/token');

$response = $http->post($token_url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $this->client_id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client_secret,
        'username'=>'my-username',
        'password'=>'my-password',
        'scope' =>'*',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
}
```

Which returns an access_token that I use in my request in my request .  I tried all the solution listed below and none of them worked :

## [.htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/452)

```
# Handle Authorization Header
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

## [Passport.php line 167](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-passport-api-unauthenticated-in-postman-using-personal-access-tokens)

```
 public static function tokensExpireIn(DateTimeInterface $date = null)
{
    if (is_null($date)) {
        return static::$tokensExpireAt
                        ? Carbon::now()->diff(static::$tokensExpireAt)
                        : new DateInterval('P1Y');
    }

    static::$tokensExpireAt = $date;

    return new static;
}
```

Please help , I'm desperate now :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is how you authenticate and which token you are using.

There are 2 ways to generate token

1. Users login and you use create token to get the token if user is authenticated.
2. Generate a client and use PRE built routes by passport to get token

Now in the API routes you have to tell in your method how you are authenticating for example

```
// Below one is for authenticating Client token  
Route::get('/test', 'Api\TestController@index')->middleware('client_credentials');
```

```
// Below one is for the User token  
Route::get('/test', 'Api\TestController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

And Remember if you are using client authentication, you have to add the below line in `routemiddleware` in `App/http/kernel.php`

`'client_credentials' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class`

I hope that solves issues

Comment: I wrongly assumed Passport would know the grant type implicitly but this explained the issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new password grant client with:

```php
php artisan passport:client --password
```

You'll get an output like:

```php
What should we name the password grant client? [Laravel Password Grant Client]:
 > 

Password grant client created successfully.
Client ID: 4
Client secret: WlRYEbA5lt5esbi0MuFyJPzPDmHDGsk3iC5QGw7d
```

Use those credentials to fill your client id and secret.  Standard client credentials created through the Vue component interface do not work for password grants.

Comment: Exactly what I did @matticistard . I ended up creating my own middleware to authenticate my requests.